# Can't indent heredoc to match code block's indentation

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, here-document

If there's a "First World Problems" for scripting, this would be it.

I have the following code in a script I'm updating:

```
if [ $diffLines -eq 1 ]; then
        dateLastChanged=$(stat --format '%y' /.bbdata | awk '{print $1" "$2}' | sed 's/\.[0-9]*//g')

        mailx -r "Systems and Operations <sysadmin@[redacted].edu>" -s "Warning Stale BB Data" jadavis6@[redacted].edu <<EOI
        Last Change: $dateLastChanged

        This is an automated warning of stale data for the UNC-G Blackboard Snapshot process.
EOI

else
        echo "$diffLines have changed"
fi
```

The script sends email without issues, but the mailx command is nested within an if statement so I appear to be left with two choices:

1. Put `EOI` on a new line and break indentation patterns or
2. Keep with indentation but use something like an echo statement to get mailx to suck up my email.

I'm open to alternatives to heredoc, but if there's a way to get around this it's my preferred syntax.

Comment: It’s very rare that you need to combine `awk` and `sed` in the same command.  Here. you could do `stat … | awk '{sub(/\.[0-9]*/, ""); print $1, $2}'`, thus doing the substitution in `awk` and eliminating the `sed`.  (Use `gsub` if there is a possibility of multiple occurrences of the pattern.)

Answer (score 187, accepted):

You can change the here-doc operator to `<<-`. 
You can then indent both the here-doc *and the delimiter* with tabs:

```
#! /bin/bash
cat <<-EOF
    indented
    EOF
echo Done
```

Note that **you must use tabs**, not spaces, to indent both the here-doc and the delimiter. This means the above example won't work copied (Stack Exchange replaces tabs with spaces). If you put any quotes around the first `EOF` delimiter, then parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion will not be in effect.

Comment: Cool, that fixes the indent problem but now it's not expanding the variable I'm trying to put in there (`$dateLastChanged`) if I do the hypen+quotes thing in your example, but if I take the hyphen and quotes out and put EOI on a new line it starts expanding it again.

Comment: @JoelDavis: Just remove the quotes, keep the hyphen.

Comment: Being forced to use tabs is very annoying. Is there a good way around it?

Comment: @con-f-use: You can try something like `cat << EOF | sed 's/^ *//'` and so on.

Comment: Or even better: `cat <<- EOF | awk 'NR==1 && match($0, /^ +/){n=RLENGTH} {print substr($0, n+1)}'`. This removes the amount of preceding spaces in the first line from every line in the here document (thanks to [anubhava](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33837099/789308)).

Comment: Actually, the only line that needs a <Tab> is the final "EOF" line.  The rest of the lines can use spaces.  (at least in Bash v4... not sure of earlier.)

Comment: @Cometsong: It doesn't remove the leading whitespace for me on bash 4.3.42.

Comment: @choroba - I just realized I'd added in the `awk` space-removal before I added that comment!  Only the final line needs to be Tab'd using that... :)

Comment: To clarify, the reason you need to use `<<-` (instead of `<<`) is because, as explained [here](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html), it strips leading *tabs*, but not spaces, in the output. Thus, to ensure your here doc has a nice readable indentation in your script, but not when it's actually written out, you need to indent your here doc with *tabs* (instead of spaces).

Comment: Similarly, to build upon this answer, let's say you wanted the content *within* your here doc to also have nested indentation -- i.e. you have the outermost level of indentation, which is just for making your script readable and which you want to be stripped, and also one/more inner levels of indentation that you want to be preserved when your here doc is actually written out.
In that case, you would have to use tabs for the outermost level of indentation, and spaces for the remaining inner levels of indentation.

Answer (score 26):

If you don't need command substitution and parameter expansion inside your here-document, you can avoid using tabs by adding the leading spaces to the delimiter:

```
$     cat << '    EOF'
>         indented
>     EOF
        indented
$     cat << '    EOF' | sed -r 's/^ {8}//'
>         unindented
>     EOF
unindented
```

I couldn't figure out a way to use this trick and keep parameter expansion, though.

Comment: To me, this is the only answer which solves the indenting problem without using spaces. `shell-check` will find any indent changes which con't match the spaces in the quoted string. Use double quotes for parameter expansion?

Comment: Nice. You can pipe thru envsubst to replace environ variables with their values.

Comment: The only downside to this issue that IDEs like VSCODE think that the HEREDOC is never closed for styling any coding following it.

Before: https://imgur.com/2xWrPSH
After: https://imgur.com/2xjvwt2

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
sed 's/^ *//' >> ~/Desktop/text.txt << EOF
    Load time-out reached and nothing to resume.
    $(date +%T) - Transmission-daemon exiting.
EOF
```

Comment: You can't have differently-indented lines within the heredoc is this case. (This matters if e.g. the contents is a script.)

Answer (score 2):

The other method would be herestrings:

```
    mail_content="Last Change: $dateLastChanged

    This is an automated warning of stale data for the UNC-G Blackboard Snapshot process."
    mailx -r "Systems and Operations <sysadmin@[redacted].edu>" -s "Warning Stale BB Data" jadavis6@[redacted].edu <<<"$mail_content"
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is GNU-Bash-specific.

The trick is that we use the `<<<` one-word here-doc offered by Bash, and we make that a multi-line item.

We also avoid a UUoC: we don't need a `cat` process to feed input to `sed`:

```
$ sed '1d;s/^    //' <<<"
    {
       TERM=$TERM
    }
    bye"
```

Output shows leading four-space indentation removed, and `$TERM` expanded:

```
{
   TERM=xterm-256color
}
bye
```

the `1d` command in `sed` is to delete the first blank line, which exists because our quoted literal starts with a newline after the opening quote.

Of course, in the real script for which this is in**dent**ed—pardon me, in**tended**ed—we would line up the braces with the `sed` command, which would be indented inside a loop or conditional.

If we start each line of the datum with a delimiter, then a simple `sed` substitution will delete a variable amount of indentation, so that the block can be freely moved around between indentation levels:

```
while command ; do
    if condition ; then
        variable=$(sed '1d;s/^.*|//' <<<"
                  |{
                  |   TERM=$TERM
                  |}
                  |bye
                  ")
    fi
done
```

One last idea is to put the indent magic into a variable which is used as a sort of macro:

```
# put in some common definitions library section
indent='sed 1d;s/^.*|//'

# ...

while command ; do
    if condition ; then
        variable=$($indent <<<"
                  |{
                  |   TERM=$TERM
                  |}
                  |bye
                  ")
    fi
done
```

We can improve this by writing a good old-fashioned function:

```
# put in some common definitions library section
ind()
{
   sed '1d;s/^.*|//' <<<$1
}

# ...

while command ; do
    if condition ; then
        variable=$(ind "
                  |{
                  |   TERM=$TERM
                  |}
                  |bye
                  ")
    fi
done
```

Then we have abstracted away the `<<<` entirely.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a here-string (`<<<`) instead of a here-document (`<<MARKER`), which at least avoids the end-of-document marker not being intended.

```bsh
if [[ true ]]; then
  # Sample indented block
  cat <<<'First line
  Second line
  '
fi
```

Output (note the trailing empty line):

```
First line
  Second line
```

You can combine this with other commands to strip indent. Here `cut` will output the fifth character onwards of each line. `-c` is character mode, and `5-` is the range of characters to output.

```bsh
if [[ true ]]; then
  # Sample indented block
  cut -c5- <<<'
    First line
    Second line
  '
fi
```

Output (note first and last line are empty):

```
First line
Second line
```

Excellent explanation of the difference at [command line - What's the difference between <<, <<< and < < in bash? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678915/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash/678919#678919).

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... Seems like you could take better advantage of the `--format` argument here to use `--printf` instead and just pass the lot over a pipe. Also, your `if...fi` is a compound command - it can take a redirect which all contained commands will inherit, so maybe you don't need to nest the heredoc at all.

```
if      [ "$diffLines" = 1 ]
then    stat --printf "Last Change: %.19y\n\n$(cat)\n" /.bbdata |
        mailx   -r  "Systems and Operations <sysadmin@[redacted].edu>" \
                -s  "Warning Stale BB Data" 'jadavis6@[redacted].edu'
else    echo    "$diffLines have changed"
fi      <<\STALE
This is an automated warning of stale data for the UNC-G Blackboard Snapshot process.
STALE
```

Comment: Yeah my previous revision said I didn't mind the `sed`/`awk` part. Part of my revision today was to take it out since it wasn't germane to the question. Either way it's six of one half a dozen of the other.

Comment: @Bratchley - damn. That last sentence is going to distract me for the rest of the day.

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: @Bratchley - Looks like a riddle.

Comment: Ha. Not sure what country you're from but that's a common phrase in the States. Just means "Different approach to the same end." Your solution does get around heredoc though.

Comment: @Bratchley - I usually use em like that. It works for functions, too. with functions its better though because the redirects aren't evaluated till theyre called - so if you tack a heredoc onto the end of `fn() { cat <&3; } 3<<INPUT` you get a free, shell-evaled fd for every call to `fn`. You can stack as many as you want and reference them anywhere within the compound command - but theyre always evaled at the first call - before any commands in `fn` execute. Im from the states - but never heard that one.

Answer (score 1):

Given that this is an aesthetic issue, here's an aesthetic solution: place some visual aid into the code which acts as a transition between the "proper" pre-heredoc indentation and temporary left-alignment of the heredoc block.

```
if [ $condition -eq 1 ]; then
              ︙
       some code
       some more code

# ____/

mailx -r "Systems and Operations <sysadmin@[redacted].edu>" -s "Warning Stale BB Data" jadavis6@[redacted].edu <<EOI
Last Change: $dateLastChanged

This is an automated warning of stale data for the UNC-G Blackboard Snapshot process.
EOI

# ____
#     \

       even more code
              ︙
else
        code
          ︙
fi
```

I find that this allows my brain to better perceive the left-aligned code
as part of the indented code around it. When I'm writing in a code editor that indicates the level of indentation with a vertical line, the above visual aid appears to merge into the indicator for the previous indent level, making the transition feel even more intuitive.
Not everyone will find this satisfying, of course,
but there don't seem to be any universally satisfying answers
for when you have space-indented code.

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround I use to cheat the "space stripping behaviour".
It allows me to write the code with indents as I want it to be human readable too.

```
#!/bin/bash

T=`echo -ne ''`

TEST_CAT()
{
    cat <<- _EOF
    Line without indent
$T  This is indented first line
    $T      Line with double indent
    $T      Again a line with double indent
        $T      Another Line with double indent
            $T$T    Note: That extra '$T' removes one indent
            $T  This is again a single indent
    _EOF

}

TEST_CAT
```

Comment: Your answer seems incomplete or erroneous. The code is not testable as is. It could be improved with additional supporting information. warning: Stack Exchange doesn' save tabs

Answer (score 0):

There have been quite many good answers to this question already. However the one thing that I would like to improve is that most answers either require the use of tabs, or they remove an arbitrary number of white spaces at the beginning of the indented code. The latter problem has even been raised as a comment by @ivan_pozdeev, but it has not been answered yet.

In my solution, I prefer variable expansion to work, so I do not quote the `EOF` as done by https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/436168/240734. Therefore, the ending `EOF` must *not* be indented. For me, that is an acceptable compromise. If you prefer the ending `EOF` to be indented too, then please see the other answers with their respective pro's and cons.

Also, I want to be able to use spaces for indenting instead of tabs, therefore the concept of https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76483/240734 does not work for me.

My solution is the following:

```bash
# This 'if' statement is only added to showcase the indenting:
if true ; then
    # Use perl in the heredoc to remove only the first 4 spaces or
    # the first tab character in the heredoc. Adjust this to the
    # indenting that is used in your heredoc. Instead of perl, also
    # sed or awk can be used.
    cat << EOF | perl -pe 's@^(    |\t)@@g' > /some/file
    # This line is not indented in the created file.
    if true ; then
        # This line is indented by 4 spaces in the created file.
        echo "hello world"
    fi || exit 1
EOF

    # Check if there heredoc file creation / redirection worked,
    # and fail if it did not:
    if test $? -ne 0 ; then
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Quoting `EOF` has nothing to do with whether the ending `EOF` has to be indented. The `-` after `<<` doesn't affect variable expansion.

Comment: @muru Quoting EOF (as https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/436168/240734 is doing) is one way to allow for indenting of EOF. But it comes at the price of loosing command substitution and parameter expansion. That is what I was referring to. Using the `<<-` operator is another way to allow for indenting of EOF. But it comes at the price of not being able to use spaces for indenting. I did not mention this because https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76483/240734 already explains this idea nicely. People that can accept using tabs may prefer that answer over mine!

Comment: Ah, then you should probably use the awk variant in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198401/70524 instead.

Comment: @muru the awk variant in unix.stackexchange.com/a/198401/70524 achieves mostly the same, but in my humble opinion it is way harder to read than my solution here. It makes use of helper function `show` that is superfluous to the problem, it also makes use of the `expand` function that converts tabs to spaces which may not be what users expect. All in all its great if that works for you, but my goal was to provide a solution that is more easy to reason about.