# Unexpected end of file in shell script

Tags: shell-script, command

Here's my script

```
#! /bin/sh

source=/Source/$1
destination=/Destination
folderParam=$(basename $source)
if /usr/bin/rsync -avh -r $source $destination; then
   cp /FolderCopyStatus/Success   /Status/Success_$folderParam;
   mysql -h ip -uroot -ppassword  << EOF
   use oct_test;
   insert into Test(Name,Value,Status) values('rsync',$folderParam,'Ok');
   EOF
else
   cp /FolderCopyStatus/Failure   /Status/Failure_$folderParam;
   mysql -h ip  -uroot -ppassword  << EOF
   use oct_test;
   insert into Test(Name,Value,Status) values('rsync',$folderParam,'Fail');
   EOF
fi
```

Error and Warning

> /FinalSync.sh: line 18: warning: here-document at line 8 delimited by
>   end-of-file (wanted `EOF') /FinalSync.sh: line 19: syntax error:
>   unexpected end of file

I know there is a simple thing that I am missing.Newbie to shell scripting.

Answer (score 1):

**EOF** should be placed on the start of line. Otherwise bash does not match  EOF, it sees "spaces EOF".

Comment: So in my case where should I keep EOF?

Comment: At the beginning of a line. Just remove white characters preceding it.

Comment: Depends, one can also indent heredocs provided the right syntax is used, see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/76481).

Comment: Thank you, don_crissti, for digging it up for me. I was not aware that bash can strip white characters here.