# Capture of logs in HTML and send via email?

Tags: shell-script, shell, email, shutdown

I have created a script to shutdown Oracle database but unable to send the output of shutdown while the database shutdown completes successfully.
I only receive email of the echo part but not the actual part of shutdown. I want to capture the output of shutdown and send it via `mailx` to my `emailid`.

Also let me know how to capture this log in HTML format and send it via `emailid`.

```
LOG_FILE="Shutdown_of_$ORACLE_SID_`hostname`_Completed_`date "+%Y_%b_%d"`.txt"   
echo "">>$LOG_FILE  
echo "">>$LOG_FILE  
echo " =========================================================  ">>$LOG_FILE
echo "">>$LOG_FILE
echo " Step  : SHUTTING Down of database                          ">>$LOG_FILE  
echo " Start : `date `                                            ">>$LOG_FILE    
echo " ========================================================   ">>$LOG_FILE

echo "">>$LOG_FILE  
echo "">>$LOG_FILE  

export SHUT=/home/oracle/SHUT.txt  
>$SHUT  
sqlplus -s / as sysdba << EOF  
set feedback off verify off termout off linesize 120 pagesize 500;  
spool $SHUT  
shut immediate;  
spool off;  
exit;  
EOF  

echo "">>$LOG_FILE  
echo " =========================================      "  >>$LOG_FILE
echo " Status : Completed                             ">>$LOG_FILE
echo " End   : `date`                                 ">>$LOG_FILE
echo " =========================================      ">>$LOG_FILE
echo "">>$LOG_FILE

mailx -s "Shutdown_of_'$ORACLE_SID'_`hostname`_Completed_`date "+%Y_%b_%d"` " email_adress@.com  < $LOG_FILE
```

**NOTE:** My Bash version: GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally do what you want like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

{
cat <<-EOF


 =========================================================  

 Step  : SHUTTING Down of database                          
 Start : `date `                                            
 ========================================================   



EOF

export SHUT=/home/oracle/SHUT.txt  
>$SHUT 

sqlplus -s / as sysdba <<-EOF  
set feedback off verify off termout off linesize 120 pagesize 500;  
spool $SHUT  
shut immediate;  
spool off;  
exit;  
EOF

cat $SHUT

cat <<-EOF

 =========================================
 Status : Completed
 End    : $(date)
 =========================================

EOF

} | mailx -s "Shutdown_of_'$ORACLE_SID'_$(hostname)_Completed_$(date "+%Y_%b_%d") " \
      email_adress@.com
```

The above creates a subshell which will capture all the output from the commands within it. We then pipe all this output to `mailx` directly.

**NOTE:** Pay special attention to any additional spacing around the `EOF` markers when using heredocs. An errant extra space at the end of the `EOF` can lead to it not working.

#### References

- [3.2.4.3 Grouping Commands](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Command-Grouping)
- [Can't indent heredoc to match nesting's indent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76481/cant-indent-heredoc-to-match-nestings-indent/76483#76483)