# bash script does not continue after executing query with sqlplus

Tags: bash, shell-script, sqlplus

here I'm trying to run a normal query with sqlplus and dump the result into CSV file, then I have another job to do, I facing problem my script does not continue after executing sqlplus query it just views the result and dumps the output into csv file but it does not continue
also i don't know how to dump the data without view the result out

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /dir/test_dir

    sqlplus -s test/test <<EOF
    set colsep ,
    set underline off,
    set headsep off,
    set feedback off,
    set long 99999,
    set linesize 32767,
    set trimspool on,
    spool report(date +%Y-%m-%d).csv
    select a.s, a.d, a.t, a.ww, a.tt from test a;
    exit;
    EOF
cd ../

mkdir test/
.
.
.
```

Comment: Possibly related: [Can't indent heredoc to match nesting's indent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76481/cant-indent-heredoc-to-match-nestings-indent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line containing `EOF` with *leading blanks* does not terminate the here document started with `<<EOF`. Use `EOF` without leading blanks. Instead of

```
    EOF
```

you should use

```
EOF
```

---

Alternatively change the line with redirection to `sqlplus -s test/test <<-EOF` and then indent with tabs.

> If the redirection operator is `<<-`, then all leading tab characters are stripped from input lines and the line containing delimiter. This allows here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a natural fashion.

<sup>([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents))</sup>

Comment: They may also want to quote the query to prevent the shell from doing expansion  in it (not really an issue in the code that they are currently showing), with `<<-'EOF'`.