# Add heredoc (<<) to end of alias within function call

Tags: bash, zsh, alias, here-document

I have an alias which is my psql connection string for a database, let's say the alias is this:

`alias GQQ='psql "host=$host user=$redshift_uname dbname=$redshift_dbname port=$port pass    word=$redshift_pwd"'`

This alias exists so I can connect to the database, but I would also like to call it within a function to send simple queries to the database.

In regular terminal I can run first: `GQQ <<EOF` second: `<QUERY> ex. SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10;` and third: `EOF`, and my query will return results.

I would like to create function which emulates this as follows:

```
function qredshift() {

    GQQ <<EOF
    $*
    EOF

}
```

But I am unsure how to formulate this, I have tried shell within shell and adding quotes in various place, what is the proper way to run this?

Comment: Given `<<EOF`, the _closing_ EOF must have **no other characters** on that line,  meaning leading/trailing whitespace is not allowed.

Comment: This syntax doesn't work though when I call the function, how do I arrange the quotes?

Comment: 1. how do you call the function: at the command line or in a script? 2. what "doesn't work", **_exactly_** (what's the error message)

Comment: You can use a herestring to avoid dealing with the indentation and tab [requirements](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/76481/) of a heredoc: `GQQ <<< "$*"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `EOF` to be the full contents of the line for it to be taken as delimiter.

```
qredshift() {
   local IFS=' '
   psql "host=$host user=$redshift_uname dbname=$redshift_dbname port=$port password=$redshift_pwd" <<EOF
$*
EOF
}
```

When $* is found in a here document, the positional parameters are joined with the first character of `$IFS` or space depending on the shell. So we set `IFS` to space so as to have a consistent behaviour between shells. In `zsh`, you can also use `${(j[ ])@}` to explicitly join on spaces.

Instead of a here document, you could use:

```
printf '%s\n' "$*" | psql...
```

Or:

```
printf '%s\n' "$@" | psql...
```

To pass each of the argument of `qreshift` as a separate line of input to `psql`.

Or use zsh-style here-strings (now also supported in bash and a few other shells):

```
psql... <<< "$*"
```

`psql` (assuming that's the postgresql client) can also be given the SQL query to execute with `-c`, so:

```
psql -c "$*" ...
```

For `qredshift` to take the SQL code either from arguments or stdin if no argument is provided, you could do:

```
qredshift() {
   local IFS=' '
   psql ${1+"-c$*"} "host=$host user=$redshift_uname dbname=$redshift_dbname port=$port password=$redshift_pwd"
}
```

Then you could either do:

```
qredshift 'select * from...'
```

```
qredshift <<< 'select * from...'
```

```
qredshift << 'EOF'
select * from...
EOF
```

Note that it's bad practice to pass passwords on the command line, as that's public information within a system.

Doing `PGPASSWORD="$redshift_pwd" psql ...` where the password is passed via an environment variable rather than in an argument is safer as environment variables are private.